# How do I extend QUnit with new assertion functions?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, qunit

I'd like to add new assertions to QUnit.
I've done something this:

```
QUnit.extend(QUnit.assert, {
  increases: function(measure, block, message){
    var before = measure();
    block();
    var after = measure();
    var passes = before < after;
    QUnit.push(passes, after, "< " + before, message);
  }
});
```

When I use `increases(foo,bar,baz)` in my test, I get

> ReferenceError: increases is not defined

From the browser console I can see `increases` is found in `QUnit.assert` along with all the other standard functions: `ok`, `equal`, `deepEqual`, etc.

From the console, running:
`test("foo", function(){console.log(ok) });`
I see the source of `ok`.

Running:
`test("foo", function(){console.log(increases) });`
I am told increases is not defined.

What is the magic required to use my increases in a test?  Also, where (if anywhere) is the documentation for that?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found the solution is to accept a parameter in the test callback function. That parameter will have the extra assertion type. So we can call it like so:

```
//the assert parameter accepted by the callback will contain the 'increases' assertion
test("adding 1 increases a number", function(assert){
    var number = 42;
    function measure(){return number;}
    function block(){number += 1;}
    assert.increases(measure, block);
});
```

Comment: That is the correct approach. If you want to use your custom assertion via a global reference like other QUnit assertions, you have to explicitly add it to the global object, usually `window`.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to add a custom assertion today and came to the same problem. **Only Original assertions functions are defined also in the global object**. Custom assertions are not.

From debugging QUnit code it seems the original assertions functions are placed on the global scope - the window variable - intentionally. This happens at the initialization of QUnit, so it only applies to the original assertions functions already defined at that time.

1.QUnit.js : Definition of the original assertions functions

```
assert = QUnit.assert = {
  ok: function( result, msg ) {

...
```

2.QUnit.js : Original assertions function -> QUnit.constructor.prototype

```
extend( QUnit.constructor.prototype, assert );
```

3.QUnit.js : QUnit.constructor.prototype -> window

```
// For browser, export only select globals
if ( typeof window !== "undefined" ) {
    extend( window, QUnit.constructor.prototype );
    window.QUnit = QUnit;
}
```

**Solution**

So as you answered, in order to use custom assertion function, one needs to:

1. Catch the `assert` argument that is passed to each assert function and use it.
   ex.

   ```
   test("test name", function(assert) {
     assert.cosutomAssertion(..); 
   ...});
   ```
2. Or use the full namespace to reach the assert function. 
   ex.

   ```
   QUnit.assert.customAssertion(..)
   ```