# How to write new assertion functions for QUnit without using QUnit.push?

Tags: javascript, qunit

I want to write a custom `assert` function for QUnit to check if an *actual* string matches an *expected* regex. With help of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19471956/419956) I wrote a first basic version that works as expected:

```
QUnit.extend(QUnit.assert, {
    matches: function (actual, regex, message) {
        var success = !!regex && !!actual && (new RegExp(regex)).test(actual);
        var expected = "String matching /" + regex.toString() + "/";
        QUnit.push(success, actual, expected, message);
    }
});

QUnit.test("New assertion smoke test", function (assert) {
    // force a failure to see the new assert work properly:
    assert.matches("flower", "gibberish");
});
```

This outputs:

> Message: Expected: "string matching /gibberish/", Actual: "flower"

Great!

However, while writing this I checked both [the `QUnit.extend` docs](https://api.qunitjs.com/QUnit.extend/) and [the QUnit.push docs](https://api.qunitjs.com/QUnit.push/). However, the latter mentions that:

> This method is **deprecated** and it's recommended to use it through its direct reference in the assertion context.

But I fail to see how I can apply this advice inside the `QUnit.extend` context.

How do I properly write a custom assertion that doesn't use the deprecated `QUnit.push` function?

Comment: Isn't this: https://api.qunitjs.com/push/ what you're looking after? There's an example at the bottom

Comment: @sirrocco Yes, it actually looks like it. Will have to give it a go to be sure. If it is, I should probably also suggest a fix to QUnit's docs, would be nice if the deprecated `push` article (the one I link to in my question) links to the new one you suggested.

Comment: @sirrocco I got around to trying your suggestion, and it works: thank you! If you want to you can duplicate my answer, and I will delete my own and award you the well-deserved bounty.

Comment: No worries @Jeroen, glad we got it sorted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by @sirrocco in a comment, there's a *different* `push` method document that you should be using for this: see [this documentation link](https://api.qunitjs.com/push/). This means your answer is as simple as changing one line of code to use `this.push` instead of `Qunit.push`:

```
this.push(success, actual, expected, message);
```

Here's a full working example:

```js
QUnit.extend(QUnit.assert, {
    matches: function (actual, regex, message) {
        var success = !!regex && !!actual && (new RegExp(regex)).test(actual);
        var expected = "String matching /" + regex.toString() + "/";
        this.push(success, actual, expected, message);
    }
});

QUnit.test("New assertion smoke test", function (assert) {
    // force a failure to see the new assert work properly:
    assert.matches("flower", /.*our.*/, "Wanted regex to match!");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/qunit/qunit-1.20.0.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/qunit/qunit-1.20.0.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="qunit"></div>
```